# how to deal with the undefined constant error

Tags: php, mysql

i do not know how i can deal with this error im getting on my code

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant result2 - assumed 'result2' in C:\xampp\htdocs\how are things\admin panel\register3.php on line 62
```

the code on line 62 is

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id ,username, user_level, type, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES('','$username', '2', 'a','$first_name', '$last_name', '$email','$password','$phone_number') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

this the code where it is found

```
if (empty($error)){
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' OR username='$username' ") or die(mysql_error());
     $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id ,username, user_level, type, first_name, last_name, email, password, phone_number) VALUES('','$username', '2', 'a','$first_name', '$last_name', '$email','$password','$phone_number') ") or die(mysql_error());
     if(!result2){
        die('Could not insert into the database: '.mysql_error());
     }

    } else{
    $error_message = '<span class="error">';
    foreach($error as $key => $Values){
    $error_message.= "$Values";

    }
    $error_message.="</span><br/><br/>";

    }
```

Comment: You're missing your `$` before `result_2`

Comment: Line 62 seems to be the next one to the one you quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!result2){
```

You missed the $ there. Please use an IDE to code, this way you can avoid this kind of mistakes

Comment: Not necessarily an IDE, but at least a text editor with syntax highlighting like vim or Notepad++.